# Processing output from R's lapply function / removing elements from lists

Tags: r, list, lapply

I would like to prune the information returned by `R`'s `lapply` function to just the 1st element.

So, for something like this

```
is(rnorm(10,10))
[1] "numeric"      "vector"       "atomicVector" "index"        "number"      ...
```

I'd like to in the end just keep just the 1st element `"numeric"`

A full example

```
x <- rnorm(10,10)
y <- sample(c("a","b","c"),10, replace = TRUE)
z <- factor(sample(c("a","b","c"),10, replace = TRUE))
dat.fake <- data.frame(x,y,z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Use lapply to get information on each column w/in dataframe

```
lapply(dat.fake,is)
```

I'd like to just get

```
$x
[1] "numeric"      
$y
[1] "character"           
$z
[1] "factor"
```

Instead of the full output of

```
$x
[1] "numeric"      "vector"       "atomicVector" ...
$y
[1] "character"           "vector"              "data.frameRowLabels" ...
[6] "index"              
$z
[1] "factor"   "integer"  "oldClass" "numeric"  "vector"
```

Is there a way to do this within `lapply` or a similar function, or what is the most efficient way to process the information in the list returned by `lapply`?

Comment: In this specific case you could use `lapply(dat.fake, class)` to return what you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, an anonymous function seems to make the most sense:

```
> lapply(dat.fake,function(x) is(x)[1])
$x
[1] "numeric"

$y
[1] "character"

$z
[1] "factor"
```

---

To answer the question posed in the title, use basic extraction:

```
> temp <- lapply(dat.fake, is)
> lapply(temp, "[", 1)
$x
[1] "numeric"

$y
[1] "character"

$z
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response!  Any general recommendations on resources for learning how to work with lists?  (books, tutorials etc).  I have Matloff's The Art of R Programming which has only the basics.  I need to learn to efficiently edit, merge, delete etc elements of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Another, much less efficient way to do this is to define a new function that extracts only the 1st elements of a vector (which is what each element in this list is) and use lapply again

New function that grabs just the 1st element of a vector

```
first.element <- function(x)
{
  x[1]
}


lapply.out <- lapply(dat.fake,is)
```

Use lapply with newfunction

```
lapply(lapply.out,first.element) #**EDITED**
```

And the output is

```
$x
[1] "numeric" 
$y
[1] "character"
$z
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: I guess you want to change `dat.fake` to `lapply.out` in the second lapply call. Also note that you could the same with the code in the second part of Ananda's answer or you could use `head`, for example: `lapply(lapply.out, head, 1)` which would also do the same.

Comment: yes, "lapply(dat.fake,first.element)" in the original should be "lapply(lapply.out, first.element)"  I have made this chagne to the code